# Spock: testing falling and successfull invocations in one feature?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

Given I want to test my method with two parameters: one should lead to success, and another one to exception.

Writing something like..

```
when:
myObject.myMethod(value);

then:
result

where:
value      | result
new Good() | notThrown(Exception)
new Bad()  | thrown(Exception)
```

.. is impossible in Spock.

How can I fix it and avoid writing two separate feature methods?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid separate tests? Remember that each test (method) should test *one and only one behavior*. Successful execution and throwing an error are two fundamental different   behaviors with (hopefully) different preconditions. So they really should have their own test tough!

Comment: Timothy, from one hand you are right, from the other one - if we are using 'where' clause in Spock we _already_ testing many behaviors in one test. If it is considered to be ok to test many incoming parameters versus many outgoing parameters, then why its wrong to test many incoming parameters vs outgoing parameters AND exceptions?

Comment: One of the big advantages of unittest is, that you can tell by the name of the test method what went wrong. But this is only possible, if each test method has only one reason to fail. Testing with multiple  inputs *may* follow that rule, but testing the "happy day" scenario and Exception handling together does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstSpec extends Specification {

    def "let's try this!"() {
        when:
        new Test().method('Good')

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        when:
        new Test().method('Bad')

        then:
        thrown(Exception)
    }

    class Test {
        def method(String param) {
            if(param == 'Good') {
                return param
            }

            throw new Exception()
        }
    }
}
```

Test it [here](https://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5164694683779072)

Comment: not all approaches which are technically possible are desirable too. This answer leads the TO into a wrong direction!

Comment: Thats ok, but can I make it via where clause?

Comment: No. **_Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication_**. Having different tests as mentioned in other comments is the best way. I answered the question with one valid possibility. Oversimplifying software is not a norm anymore. Make the tests readable for a developer not for the compiler.